# Event handler 1 interrupted by Event handler 2

Tags: c#

I have a C# program   .Net Framework 4.8
The Form has a Button
The Form has a groupbox with 3 radio buttons  `Radiobutton1`, `Radiobutton2` and `Radiobutton3`

`Radiobutton1.Checked = true;`   This is the state of the radio buttons at the beginning of the program.

```
namespace Event_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button Click Started");
            radioButton2.Checked = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("Button Click Finished");
        }

        private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Check Change Started");

            Debug.WriteLine("Check Change Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output

> Button Click Started
> Check Change Started
> Check Change Finished
> Check Change Started
> Check Change Finished
> Button Click Finished

I thought the Button Clicked event handler would finish before the Check Change event handler was called.  Obviously this is not true.

Does anyone have an insight into why this happens.

Thanks

Comment: if `radioButton2` is set to `false` then `radioButton2.Checked = true;` should immediately raise the changed event. Any particular reason why do you expect it to be raised with some delay?

Comment: Additionally, you get two sets of ‛CheckChanged‛ events since the previous RadioButton fires when it is un-checked, and then the second one fires from the new RadioButton becoming checked.

Comment: It seems odd that the OS would not let the first message handler finish its task before sending another message in the same thread.